# IIS FTP error: 426 Connection closed; transfer aborted

Tags: iis, ftp

I have an IIS FTP set up on Windows 2003 SP2 (S1). Everyday in the early morning, a script on another server (S2) will run and initiate FTP transfer of pulling log files from S1 to S2. The FTP client we're using is built-in FTP.exe in Windows 2000 on S2.

Recently we replaced S1 with a new server however we kept the IP address. There are multiple IP addresses on new S1.

Ever since the new S1 was in place, the '426 Connection closed; transfer aborted.' errors haven been occuring randomly. The log indicated that the transfer started ok however the file cannot be transferred completely, as per log below:

```
mget access*.log
200 Type set to A.
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for access02232010.log(205777167 bytes).
426 Connection closed; transfer aborted.
ftp: 20454832 bytes received in 283.95Seconds 72.04Kbytes/sec.
```

The firewall monitor suggested that the connection was setup in passive mode however I've been told that MS FTP.exe doesn't support passive mode. Though I can see the response of 'entering passive mode' from server when typing in 'quote pasv'.

My network admin has told me to try the transfer in active mode however I don't know how to open active mode on client side. It's getting really frustrating. Wish someone here has the right knowledge/experience could shed me a light.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally resolved by setting NIC on FTP server from 'half-duplex' to 'full duplex'.

Answer (score 0):

check this out https://forums.iis.net/t/1105801.aspx